# How to get a post{} section executed in a nested stage{} block in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

How do I get the following `post` section to run?
The idea is to generate parallel running stages as per the contents of `myList`.

```
stage("Dynamic stages"){
  steps{
    stageMap = [:]
    script {
      for (element in myList) {
        stageMap[element] = {
          stage("Stage 1 of ${element}"){
            echo "Stage 1"
          }
          stage("Stage 2 ${element}"){
            echo "Stage 2"
            post{
              failure{
                echo "Stage 2 failed!"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    parallel stageMap
  }
}
```

The build fails with the following error

```
Also:   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'post' found among steps...
```

The [Jenkins doc](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post) however says it is allowed

Sure enough there is a big list of allowed steps and post is not among those.
Am I missing something or is the doc not clear about this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`post{}` is only available in declarative pipeline, but not within a scripted section of a declarative pipeline. You can use `try{} catch{}` instead.

There is another error: You are using loop variable `element` within a closure, which doesn't work as expected. The closure captures the `element` variable, but when the closure runs, its value will always be the last value of the loop. To fix this, I have assigned the loop variable to new local variable `curElement`, which will be a new instance for every iteration, so it gets captured as expected.

```java
stage("Dynamic stages"){
  steps{
    stageMap = [:]
    script {
      for (element in myList) {
        def curElement = element

        stageMap[element] = {
          stage("Stage 1 of ${curElement}"){
            echo "Stage 1"
          }
          stage("Stage 2 ${curElement}"){
            echo "Stage 2"
            try {
                // some steps that may fail
            }
            catch( Exception e ) {
                echo "Stage 2 failed! Error: $e"
                throw  // Rethrow exception, to let the build fail.
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    parallel stageMap
  }
}
```

Comment: After a lot of surfing I did reach that conclusion, that maybe `post` is not applicable inside `script`. But was still hoping to be wrong. I wonder if it works outside the `scripts` but inside `steps`. And thanks for catching the problem with using the loop variable directly. I have that fix in my actual code, but forgot to add here in the example.

Comment: @BladedProgrammer Re `post`, the docs say: "Allowed In the top-level pipeline block and each stage block.". So you can only have it like this `stage("Dynamic stages"){ steps{} post {} }`

Comment: Ok so it has to be exactly just at one level into a stage block. I took that to mean as anywhere deep inside a stage block.